# FLASK-WTF update a unique column PYTHON/FLASK/SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

The def clean_clean email isn't working. This function should do two things as shown by two ifs. The first checks if no changes have been made  to the field and if no changes have been made validation doesn't start, this currently work. The second if should check if the email entered already exists and if so present a validation error message. As the second if doesn't if an exisitng email is entered this leads to SQL IntegrityError.

Model.py - table

```
class User(db.Model, TimestampMixin, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
```

forms.py

```
   class EditUserForm(FlaskForm):
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    update = SubmitField('Update')
    cancel = SubmitField('Cancel')

    def clean_email(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        email = cd(email=email.data)

        # if email is not modified, so don't start validation flow
        if self.instance.pk is not None and self.instance.email == email:
            return cd

        # check email is unique or not
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Email address already exists!".format(email))
        return cd
```

SQL error when a existing email is entered

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: user.email
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail, such as the SQL error?

Answer (score 0):

In reference to this error listed:

> sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: user.email

This means that you're trying to save a new entry into your 'user' table with an email that already exist. You must have the constraint in your models.py file that says something like

```
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

If you want users to be able to save an email that's already being used by a different user, then you need to change this to...

```
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
```

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but if you want to do a query to find if the email is in use by someone besides the current user, you could do something like this:

```
email_already_in_use_boolean = bool(db.session.query(User).filter(User.email==email.data).filter(User.id!=current_user_id).first())
```

Comment: Did this answer help you?